# Integral Beta function related

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Can anyone help me with calculating $$\int_0^z (xz-x^2)^{1/2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Is it possible with partial integration or substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be doable by a chain of substitutions, as soon as you complete the square:

$$I=\int_0^z \sqrt{\frac{z^2}{4} -\left(x-\frac{z}{2}\right)^2} ~ dx $$

Then $ u = x-\frac{z}{2}$ and obviously $ dx = du$.

Now

$$ I = \int_{-\frac{z}{2}}^{\frac{z}{2}} \sqrt{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2 - u^2} ~ du$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using Beta function.

We start with the substitution $ x \mapsto zx $.

$$\begin{align} \int_0^z (xz-x^2)^{1/2}\, \mathrm dx &= z^2 \int_0^1 (x-x^2)^{1/2}\, \mathrm dx\\ &= z^2 \int_0^1 x^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}\, \mathrm dx  \\ &= z^2 \mathrm{B}(3/2,3/2) \\ &= \dfrac{z^2\Gamma(3/2) \Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(3)} \\   \int_0^z (xz-x^2)^{1/2}\, \mathrm dx&= \dfrac{\pi z^2}{8} \end{align}$$